# Наследование классов и выделение памяти

Tags: c++

Объясните пожалуйста механику того, как это работает.

```
class Parent
{
  protected:
    int parentInt;
  public:
    void printInt() {std::cout << parentInt;}
};

class Child : public Parent
{
  private:
    int childInt;
  public:
    void printInt() 
    {
      Parent::printInt();
      std::cout << parentInt;
    }
};

Parent* = kids[10];
kids[0] = new Child;
```

Я создал массив указателей родительского типа, но при создании объекта дочернего класса я всё равно могу помещать его в массив указателей на родительский тип? Как это работает?

То есть, при создании объекта мне выделяется столько памяти, чтобы там уместились все мои переменные и методы. В наследнике я, получается, **добавляю** какие-то еще переменные, то есть сам объект занимает больше памяти, а всё равно могу обращаться по указателю на родительский тип, который, вроде, меньше. Надеюсь, ясно изложил мысль. Сам плохо понимаю. :)

Comment: П - полиморфизм

Comment: Я хочу понять, это какая-то магия закулисная, которую компилятор кастует, или есть некий прозрачный механизм, который в рантайме понимает, что это наследник родителя, а потому я выделю тут ещё на 4, 8, 100 байт больше, просто потому что насдедник?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"при создании объекта дочернего класса я всё равно могу помещать его в массив указателей на родительский тип"* - нет вы этого не можете. В примере вы преобразуете указатель на дочерний тип к указателю на родительский тип и помещаете его в массив указателей на родительский тип.

*"при создании объекта мне выделяется столько памяти, чтобы там уместились все мои переменные и методы"* - нет, методы объектов никогда в нем не хранятся.

Comment: Но где я что-то преобразую? Я же определенно говорю в том коде `kids[0] = new Child;`, где `kids[0]` это указатель на **родительский** тип, а кладу я туда уже наследника. Или где происходит преобразование?

Comment: @AlexSazonov В этой строчке и происходит. `kids[0] = new Child` это всё равно что `Parent* p = new Child`

Comment: @AlexSazonov Вы кладете туда не наследника `Child`, а указатель на наследника `Child *`. Такой указатель может неявно преобразовываться в указатель на родительский класс `Parent *` потому что наследование представляет собой отношение "является"

Comment: То есть это происходит за кулисами и делается компилятором автоматически? На основании того, что эти два класса имеют связь Родитель -> Наследник?

Comment: @AlexSazonov Да, но можно сделать и явно `kids[0] = static_cast<Parent *>(new Child);`